# how can I transfer authentication from domain to subdomain?

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on

I want to know how do I transfer authentication from domain to subdomain in laravel. That means that I am at login situation at  mydomain.com. Then I want go to the subdomain.mydomain.com with same authentication without filling the login credential.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is to share your session across multiple subdomains. In Laravel you can do it by editing the session configuration file, located in  `config/session.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

//NOTE THE . (dot) before the domain name. 
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', .mydomain.com),
```

or as you can see by adding a `SESSION_DOMAIN` variable to your `.env` with the same value

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.com
```

Don't forget to clear all the cookies (if you are using cookies to store session) and better would be to try from a new browser, cause older sessions stored and not removed can cause some problem when the configuration just changed.